# Why is "if" an unexpected token in my code?

Tags: ocaml

Here are the first three lines of my code:

```
let day_of_week (year: int) (month: int) (day: int): int =
    if year < 2010 || year > 2019 then failwith "year out of range"
    if month < 1 || month > 12 then failwith "invalid month"
```

I get "unexpected token "if"; Error: Syntax error" for the second if. How come?

Comment: shouldn't there be an `else` in front the second `if' : http://ocaml.org/tutorials/if_statements_loops_and_recursion.html?

Comment: If you used an editor that performs indentation for you (e.g emacs with tuareg-mode) and had only one instruction per line, you would detect this kind of problem instantly because the indendation would not be what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is this :

```
let day_of_week (year: int) (month: int) (day: int): int =
      if year < 2010 || year > 2019 then failwith "year out of range" 
      else if month < 1 || month > 12 then failwith "invalid month" 
      else day ;;
val day_of_week : int -> int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Since the `failwith` function raises an exception, you do not **have** to use `if … then … else …` but if you decide to use only `if … then …` you have to use `;` to indicate when a new expression is starting:

```
# let day_of_week (year: int) (month: int) (day: int): int =
        if year < 2010 || year > 2019 then failwith "year out of range" ;
        if month < 1 || month > 12 then failwith "invalid month" ;
        day ;;
val day_of_week : int -> int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

Comment: The semicolons did not seem to help. Any other suggestions?

Comment: The line `val day_of_week : int -> int -> int -> int = <fun>` was not typed by me and means in both cases that the function definition was validated by my toplevel, OCaml version 4.00.1 (but the syntax has not changed for ages).